# OpenCV using static libraries for Android application

Tags: c++, android-studio, opencv, android

I have integrated `OpenCV 4.3.0` in my `Android Studio 4.0` application. I have to install the OpenCV Manager on my target Android device to make my application work.

I have followed below link to integrate the OpenCV:
https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

As per the above link, I have the static `OpenCV` libraries in my `Android` application.

In my code, I just open the camera preview for testing. My application fails to load the static libraries and I have to install OpenCV Manager on my Android device then only my application works perfectly.

Also, my Android project has the libraries included under the `jniLinbs` folder `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a`, `x86`, and `x86_64`. But still, I have to use OpenCV Manager Application for accessing the Camera Preview. I have the below code to initialize.

```
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
  // This code is getting executed  
  Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
  OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_4_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
  mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
}
```

Am I missing anything?

I want to avoid using the OpenCV Manager Application and have all the libraries integrated into one Android application.

Answer (score 1):

- New versions of OpenCV for Android are often unstable
- Please download opencv-3.4.3-android-sdk.zip here and your problem will be solved: https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.4.3/
- Good luck to you!